# R: ggplot2: quickest way of obtaining statistical information about data in bins produced by geom_bar() or stat_bin()

Tags: r, ggplot2

For example, say I have the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
df = diamonds
dfs = df[sample(nrow(df), 100, replace = FALSE),]
ggplot(dfs, aes(x = carat)) +
    geom_bar(breaks = seq(0,2, by = 0.5), colour = 'white')
```

What is the quickest/most elegant way of obtaining the most common `cut`, or the average `depth`, or the median `price` (etc etc) of each of the bins?

Comment: Do you want to do it inside ggplot?

Comment: Roland's answer seems nice, and easy to implement. I'd be interested to see if one could do it within `ggplot2` also.

Comment: @user32259, yes I would also be very interested in knowing how to get at the results of the calculations done by stat_bin and the other stat_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- diamonds
set.seed(42)
dfs <- df[sample(nrow(df), 100, replace = FALSE),]

library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(dfs)
DT[,bins:=findInterval(carat,seq(0,2, by = 0.5))]
setkey(DT,bins)

#most common cut
DT[,names(which.max(table(cut))),by=bins]

#   bins      V1
#1:    1   Ideal
#2:    2 Premium
#3:    3   Ideal
#4:    4 Premium
#5:    5   Ideal

#note that there is a carat==2.01, which you did not plot
```

Comment: yeah, sorry deleted my comment, and have just seen yours. realised the error (i was at first evaluating `table(cut)` outside of the second argument of `DT`).